# Importing a jsx file in a node js firebase function

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to import a react jsx file like so:
`import TestEmail from "./TestEmail.jsx";`

Here is the function:

```
import {SendGridHelper} from "./sendgrid";
import {logError} from "../../../../../helpers/logger";
import TestEmail from "./TestEmail.jsx";
import {render} from '@react-email/render';

export async function getSendEmail(): Promise<void> {
  const sendGridHelper = new SendGridHelper(process.env.SENDGRID_API_KEY);

  const emailHtml = render(TestEmail({ username: "Bob" }));

  await sendGridHelper
      .sendEmail(
          "Test",
          {
            name: "Name",
            email: "noreply@example.com",
          },
          "bob@example.com",
          {
            html: emailHtml,
          },
      )
      .catch((e) => {
        logError(
            e,
            "Error sending email",
            `Test`,
            JSON.stringify(e?.response.body)
        );
      });
}
```

And how I setup my routes:

```
setupRoutes(
  app,
  [
    {
      path: "/v1/public/profiles/email",
      method: HttpMethod.GET,
      func: getSendEmail,
    },
  ],
  true
);

export const publicProfiles = https.onRequest(app);
```

And here is my react "email" component:

```
import {
    Body,
    Container,
    Font,
    Head,
    Heading,
    Html,
    Preview,
    Tailwind,
} from '@react-email/components';

export const TestEmail = ({username = 'Bob', }) => {
    const previewText = `Join ${username}`;

    return (
        <Html>
            <Head>
                <Font
                    fontFamily="Inter"
                    fallbackFontFamily="Verdana"
                    webFont={{
                        url: 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Inter&display=swap',
                    }}
                    fontWeight={400}
                    fontStyle="normal"
                />
            </Head>
            <Preview>{previewText}</Preview>
            <Tailwind>
                <Body className="bg-[#0f0f12] my-auto mx-auto font-sans">
                    <Container className="rounded-xl my-[40px] mx-auto p-[20px] max-w-[600px] bg-[#18181b]">
                        <Heading className="text-white text-[24px] font-normal text-center p-0 my-[30px] mx-0">
                            Join <strong>{username}</strong>
                        </Heading>
                    </Container>
                </Body>
            </Tailwind>
        </Html>
    );
};

export default TestEmail;
```

The reason is I will take that React component and render the html from it to use to send an email.

However when I run my firebase functions emulator I get this message:

```
⬢  functions: Failed to load function definition from source: FirebaseError: Failed to load function definition from source: Failed to generate manifest from function source: Error: Cannot find module './TestEmail.jsx'
```

However my IDE is able to find that file (I can click through to it).

Any ideas?

Comment: can you please post your entire code or a fiddle link if possible?

Comment: ok done so, let me know if there is something more you need

Comment: ok thanks. Are you using `default export` in TestEmail.jsx file ?

Comment: I am. Also just attached in my TestEmail code

Comment: I'm trying to do the same thing now with `react-email` and `resend` but I'm facing the same issue. Have you found a way to resolve this?